# System.AccessViolationException when using Excel.Worksheet.Copy

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

We have a VSTO addin for Excel.  The main functionality creates reports that are used to generate workbooks.  When I run a batch of reports, I get a System.AccessViolationException when using Excel.Worksheet.Copy, which also crashes Excel.  Here's how I recreate it:

1) Open and run report #1 with a single parameter which creates one workbook.  We close the workbook.
2) Open and run the same report with several parameters. This create 5 workbooks but crashes when creating the second, but ONLY if we have run the first single output report (see step 1).  If we remove the report from step 1 from the batch, this creates all 5 workbooks without error.

I've checked to make sure that the sheet we are copying is from the workbook is open, and is not referencing the first report.  In fact, we close the first one so I know that it's not.  Again, this ONLY happens if we have the report in step one, which it does not access at all, so how could that be affecting a sheet from a completely different workbook?

This doesn't even finish out my try/catch so that I can get more info.  It simply blows up Excel and I have to restart.

UPDATE:
Here's the basic code:

```
function void ReplaceSheets(Dictionary<Excel.Worksheet, IReportSheet> sheetReports)
{
    List<string> oldNames = new List<string>(sheetReports.Count);

    foreach (Excel.Worksheet oldSheet in sheetReports.Keys)
    {
        Excel.Worksheet veryHiddenSheet = null;
        Excel.Worksheet newSheet = null;

        try
        {
            string sheetName = oldSheet.Name;
            veryHiddenSheet = WorkbookHelper.FindSheet(this.DocumentView, MakeHiddenSheetName(sheetName, "--VH--"));  
            veryHiddenSheet.Visible = Excel.XlSheetVisibility.xlSheetVisible;  //Sheet has to be visible to get the copy to work correctly.
            veryHiddenSheet.Copy(this.DocumentView.Sheets[1], Type.Missing);//This is where it crashes
            newSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)this.DocumentView.Sheets[1];  //Get Copied sheet
            /* do other stuff here*/
        }
        finally
        {
            veryHiddenSheet = null;
            newSheet = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Would help to post your code, or a something smaller which reproduces the problem if your code is large.  Otherwise it's pretty hard to suggest what the issue might be.

Comment: @TimWilliams The code is rather large.  The sample that I put in only works if you can create the exact steps that I wrote up above.  If you just run this code everything works fine.  It's only in the specific case above.

Comment: @Erick: Did you find any solution for this. I am encountering same issue

Comment: @user2081126 I never did, and I don't work for that company anymore. Probably the best way is to look at the Javascript library for Office. You can use React and other JS tools.

Answer (score 0):

I never found a way in VSTO to "fix" this. I switched code to [NetOffice](http://netoffice.codeplex.com/), and I was able to get some better error message. Excel/Com was not releasing the memory attached to the spreadsheets. I rebuilt the reports from blank 2010 spreadsheets and it took care of it. I think it was a corrupted 2007 spreadsheet that may have occured on converting to 2010 or something like that.  I recommend [NetOffice](http://netoffice.codeplex.com/) over VSTO because the exception handling is far superior, and you have access to the source code, but it does have it's quirks. (You'll need to pay attention to loading order for taskpanes.)